# Animate SVG infinitely from value to value to original from value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, svg

Is it possible to use the `<animate>` tag in an svg to either make a part of an svg image animation from a value to another, to another. Or even better animate infinitely from and then to and back to from and then to; and, so on?

I want to animate a circle's radius, but in that infinite fashion. If I can't do it with the `<animate>` tag, how else can I do it?

Here is wha tI have so far for the animation running once.

```
<svg>
    <circle r="100" cx="100" cy="100" fill="slategrey">
        <animate attributeName="r" from="0" to="100" dur="1.6s"/>
    </circle>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `from` and `to`, use the `values` attribute to make it cycle back and forth, and the `repeatCount` attribute to make it repeat forever.

```
<svg>
    <circle r="100" cx="100" cy="100" fill="slategrey">
        <animate attributeName="r" values="0;100;0" dur="1.6s" 
                 repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </circle>
</svg>
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/G9R8d/)